# menu when hovered moves other menu to the right

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

so i have this menu setup everything is working but the problem is when i hover on the menu it should only drop the menu but what happens to me is that the menu drops down and the menu that i was pointing adds some blank space on the right on it. heres the look.

http://prntscr.com/4sjqzi

there should be no space from my first menu

CSS:-

```
.menu {
     width:auto;
     float:left;
     display:block;
 }
 .children {
     display:none;
 }
 #navcontainer {
     display:inline;
     padding:0px;
     margin: 0px;
     /*-8px 0 0 10px;*/
     list-style:none;
     position:relative;
     z-index:1;
     float:left;
     height: 20px;
 }
 #navcontainer ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
     text-align: left;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li {
     display: block;
     float: left;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: .2em 1em;
     color: #b37032;
     background-color: #dbd2c1;
     width: 100%;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li ul li {
     display:block;
     width:auto;
     float: none;
     background:#edebd7;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li ul li a {
     background: transparent !important;
     color: #724e32;
     border-top: 0px !important;
     border-left: 0px !important;
     border-right: 0px !important;
     ;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
     ;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
     ;
     border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
     ;
     background-color: transparent !important;
     ;
     opacity: 1 !important;
     ;
 }
 #navcontainer li:hover ul {
     display: block;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li:hover a {
     color: #724e32;
     border-top: 1px solid #694b0a;
     border-left: 1px solid #694b0a;
     border-right: 1px solid #694b0a;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
     background-color: #edebd7;
     opacity: 0.5;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li a:hover {
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #d3c096;
 }
 #navcontainer li:hover ul.children {
     left:0;
     top:29px;
     background:#edebd7;
     color:#724e32;
     padding:5px;
     border-left:1px solid #694b0a;
     border-right:1px solid #694b0a;
     border-bottom:1px solid #694b0a;
     white-space:nowrap;
     width:160px;
     height:auto;
     z-index:300;
     -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
     -webkit-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
     border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li ul li:hover {
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #d3c096;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li ul li a:hover {
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #d3c096;
 }
 #navcontainer ul li ul li:hover a {
     color: #fff;
     background-color: transparent;
 }
```

heres my html im using wordpress

```
<section class="twelve columns clearfix" style="background:transparent">
<div id="navcontainer">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?></div>
</section>
```

Comment: How about your html as well?

Comment: posted. im working on wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are wrapping your title and dropdown all with a div and that div is floated. When you turn on the dropdown div it makes the wrapper div become larger and forces the float to readjust.
Maybe you can separate the menu div divs from the dropdown divs. Then they won't affect each other.

Comment: Or make the dropdown div's positioning to absolute so it doesn't expand the menu div

Comment: i adjust my submenu position to absolute it doesnt expand my main menu but it positioned my submenu on the bottom of the first menu not on the menu i am hovering.

http://prntscr.com/4sjy1j

Comment: If you are going to go the absolute positioning route, then it's probably the main menu items that want to be absolutely positioned...but using absolute position feels wrong in this case.

Comment: i dont think i'll be able to divide my divs since my code for the menu is auto generated. making my menu positioned absolute doesnt do anything. compare to what you said to position my submenu to absolute. it work but it doesnt drops the menu on its on tab.

Comment: Maybe (as @Macsupport suggested), you could put your code up on  Jsfiddle or some-such. That will probably help in finding you a solution. Even if it is auto-generated, put the generated code up.

Comment: i cant put everything in here since im using wordpress. it must be still connect to it so that the code will work perfectly. thanks btw it help alot. i just need to figure out how to align my submenu to my menu. (y)